# Import from dbf - collation

Tags: sql-server-2012, collation, openrowset, visual-foxpro

I select data from dbf files through OPENROWSET Visual FoxPro OLEDB.
Despite forcing collation on columns (e.g. `SELECT name COLLATE Polish_CI_AS FROM Employees`) the polish specific characters keep being different characters.

Due to the data model complexity, nested replace statements are not desired.
Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: ,Are you getting any collation error.

Comment: I'm not, select works fine without any errors.

Comment: A quick search suggests you may need to specify (in OPENROWSET) the code page the data in your DBF files are currently using. For details see [this question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4478b233-51df-42e8-8938-85c8f6c75f82/read-unicode-character-using-openrowset?forum=transactsql) at MSDN Forums.

Comment: Thank you, Andriy. Any idea how to insert CharacterSet statement into this query: SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('VFPOLEDB','FilePath\FileName.DBF';'';'','SELECT * FROM FileName')

Comment: No idea, sorry. And it doesn't help that the driver is 32-bit while my server instance is 64-bit, or I would've played around with OPENROWSET arguments to try and find a way (although I must say the syntax that goes with VFPOLEDB is sooooo unintuitive, to put it mildly).