# Force collation when querying Visual FoxPro through OPENROWSET

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

How can I force collation in the following DBF select statement:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET
  ('VFPOLEDB','FilePath\FileName.DBF';'';'','SELECT *  FROM FileName')
```

I've tried with COLLATE to each column individually but it doesn't work.

(For background, see [this thread](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/129390/import-from-dbf-collation?noredirect=1#comment241754_129390).)

Comment: What is the default collation of the database in which you are doing this `SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET`? Is it `Polish_CI_AS `? If not, can you create a test DB to try this on? Execute: `CREATE DATABASE [PolishCollation] COLLATE Polish_100_CI_AS;`. The, execute: `USE [PolishCollation]; SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(...);`.

Comment: Done exactly as you said, didn't work.